# Tool to replay access.log files with cookies?

Tags: http, testing, load-testing, logging

Is there any tool that will replay combined access.log-style (or any other format) files back and preserve the cookies?

We need to load test our application with real user accesses but we really need those cookies there. I evaluated JMeter (won't work, you can enable a cookie jar but not read cookies from the log), httperf (also simulates cookie jar), siege (same) and I am stuck.

There are plenty of other tools out there but I couldn't find any that would send cookies along.

Comment: The combined log format doesn't include cookies.  Where are you going to get them from?

Comment: I added the Cookie header to the end of each line.

Answer (score 1):

It's not exactly rocket science to script this.

But it rather presupposes that:

1. you've logged the relevant cookies
2. there are no POSTs on the site
3. there is **no session fixation protection** on the site
4. indeed, that the session management is very, very crude.

libcurl supports setting cookies explicitly before the call

Comment: All those conditions hold true. And yes, scripting will be the next step if nothing comes up, but there are advantages to using a tool (it's presumably already tested, comes with neat options to control throughput and generate reports, and so on.).